# converting list of string to list of integer

Tags: python, list, input, integer

How do I convert a space separated integer input into a list of integers?

Example input:

```
list1 = list(input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: "))
```

Example conversion:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']  to  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`map()` is your friend, it applies the function given as first argument to all items in the list.

```
map(int, yourlist)
```

since it maps every iterable, you can even do:

```
map(int, input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: "))
```

which (in python3.x) returns a map object, which can be converted to a list.
I assume you are on python3, since you used `input`, not `raw_input`.

Comment: +1 but did you mean `map(int,yourlist)` ?

Comment: do you mean `map(int, input().split())`, or does py3k automatically convert space-separated input into a list?

Comment: no, I assumed that the digits are entered without whitespace, as the provided example suggests. In fact, I did not post this as a solution, I just wanted to point out that the second argument to map() does not have to be a list, any iterable works.

Answer (score 15):

One way is to use list comprehensions:

```
intlist = [int(x) for x in stringlist]
```

Comment: +1, `[int(x) for x in input().split()]` to conform OP's specs.

Answer (score 3):

this works:

```
nums = [int(x) for x in intstringlist]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
x = [int(n) for n in x]
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  `int` is not a method on strings.

Comment: Sorry I edited it... This is actually what I meant :)

Comment: It's not wrong, but I generally wouldn't reuse `x` like that.

Comment: Can you give me an example why?

Answer (score 1):

Say there is a list of strings named *list_of_strings* and output is list of integers named *list_of_int*. *map* function is a builtin python function which can be used for this operation.

```
'''Python 2.7'''
list_of_strings = ['11','12','13']
list_of_int = map(int,list_of_strings)
print list_of_int
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 l=['1','2','3','4','5']

for i in range(0,len(l)):
    l[i]=int(l[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just curious about the way you got '1', '2', '3', '4' instead of 1, 2, 3, 4. Anyway.

```
>>> list1 = list(input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: "))
Enter the unfriendly numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4
>>> list1 = list(input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: "))
Enter the unfriendly numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list1 = list(input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: "))
Enter the unfriendly numbers: '1234'
>>> list1 = list(input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: ")) 
Enter the unfriendly numbers: '1', '2', '3', '4'
>>> list1
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Alright, some code

```
>>> list1 = input("Enter the unfriendly numbers: ")
Enter the unfriendly numbers: map(int, ['1', '2', '3', '4'])
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```