# Changing a list of strings into integers

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, integer

I have the following list of strings of integers:

```
li = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

What does my code need to be for my output to be the following?:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I tried doing both:

```
" ".join(str(val) for val in li)
```

and

```
" ".join(li)
```

but both of them don't work.

I want to get rid of the brackets, the quotation marks, and the commas.

Comment: Do you want to save that as a string, or just print it?

Comment: I want to save it so that I can use it somewhere else. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Both of those solutions should already work. Remember that if you just enter an expression at the interpreter, it'll output the `__repr__()` of the returned object, which will produce `'1 2 3 4 5 6 7'` for this. If you don't want the quotes, use the actual `print()` function.

Comment: You mean to print it to some output stream, e.g. a file object.  First do as suggested:  ```out = ' '.join( ['1','2','3'] )```. Next , ```f = open('test.txt', 'w')``` ; ```f.write( out )``` ; ```f.close()``` or ```print(out)```.  I have to assume this is what you want to do because your statement **"get rid of the brackets, quotations ... etc "** makes little sense when speaking about a variable within a python routine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to apply `int()` to every element in the list:

```
map(int, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

If you just want to print the numbers as a string, you can simply do:

```
' '.join(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Does map(int, li) work as well? I just set a different variable list1 equal to a list of big numbers in quotation marks ['150', '230', '132', '184', '353'], did map(int, list1) and then did " ".join(list1) but I get the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10." @alfasin

Comment: This question has been answered before, for example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351772/converting-list-of-string-to-list-of-integer.  @alfasin - this could be a reason for downvoting however that was already done when I viewed the question.

Comment: @TrisNefzger the right reaction should be voting to close as dup - not to downvote answers. oh well...  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @qlzlahs you mixed both answers... I showed you two options - you should use either the first or the second - not both at the same time ;)